# using for loop and windows tasklist cmd i am trying to open several programs from a batch file which are not already running

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, windows-10

My code below doesn't work

```
echo will now go ahead and load the essential programs needed for 
project: %project%
set "programlistopen=sublime_text.exe xampp-control.exe"                 
for /f "delims=" %%j in (%programlistopen%) do ( 
if %%j=="sublime_text"(set pathtopen=%defaultpath%\Sublime_Text&&set 
dirpath="%workdirectory%\%project%") else
if %%j=="xampp-control.exe"(set pathtopen=%xampp%\&&set dirpath=)
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%j" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%%j">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto notstartedsublimetext
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto startedsublimetext
:notstartedsublimetext
Echo started %%j at %time%
pause
start /d "%pathtopen%" %%j %dirpath%
:startedsublimetext
echo %%j is already running......
)
```

Comment: Is the real look of your code?There are few problems.`IF` needs spaces  around the brackets.You need delayed expansion.`goto` breaks `if` and `for` contexts so you should consider using subroutines.

Comment: You don't want to use a `FOR /F`, just use a regular `FOR` command. Regardless of that, your question is off topic because you didn't actually ask a question.  All you have said is your code does not work.

Comment: Thank's @npocmaka for the edit i was working on it,anyway i have used setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and add space between the if brackets,not sure if i am using the right `for` switch

Comment: @Squashman my question is everywhere including the `<title></title>` of this page

Comment: @Vibrations, I guess my Language Arts education was different then yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest possibly changing the structure to this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\Program Files\SomeName\madeup.exe"
    "C:\Users\Vibrations\Portables\Some Name\dummy.exe"
    "C:\Windows\built-in.exe"
) Do TaskList|FindStr/BRIC:"%%~nxA\>">Nul&&(Echo %%~nxA already running
)||(Start "" "%%~A"&Echo Started %%~nxA at %TIME%)
Pause
```

*Just list the full paths to the executables you want to check/start similarly to the three I've used as an example*

**Edit**

As a result of the latest comment, here is an example of what I assume you're trying to do by way of your modification, *(replace from line `6`)*:

```bat
)||(If "%%~nxA"=="sublime_text.exe" (Start "" "%%~A" "%workdirectory%\%project%"
    ) Else Start "" "%%~A"
    Echo Started %%~nxA at %TIME%)
Pause
```

Comment: Thank's mate, @Compo it worked but not to the degree i wanted it to,thus i modified it as below 
`||(if %%~nxA == "sublime_text.exe" set dirpath="%workdirectory%\%project%"
if %%~nxA == "xampp-control.exe" set dirpath=
echo %dirpath%
Start "" "%%~A" %dirpath%&Echo Started %%~nxA at %TIME%)
Pause` However the if statements i added are being ignored i cannot understand why, i can't seem to find any documentation on the `BRIC` switch command,could you please clue me in as to what it does mate?

Comment: @Vibrations, I've made an **Edit** to my answer to try to replicate what I think your comment is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks mate, it now works like a charm,have a nice `%TimeofDay%`:-)

Comment: @Vibrations, if my answer is your preferred solution, please consider marking it as accepted, _by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer_.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

@rem Variables to be set.
@rem   changedir is an optional pushd on each call of :notstarted.
@rem   startdir is passed to the /d argument in the start command.
@rem   programpath is the path to the program executable.
@rem   args are any arguments to pass to the program executable.
@rem Variables are undefined at start of loop.

echo will now go ahead and load the essential programs needed for project: %project%

set "programlistopen=wordpad.exe notepad.exe"

for %%j in (%programlistopen%) do (
    for %%B in (changedir startdir programpath args) do set "%%~B="

    if "%%~j" == "wordpad.exe" (
        set "changedir=%userprofile%"
        set "startdir=%cd%"
        set "programpath=C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories"
    ) else if "%%~j" == "notepad.exe" (
        rem Nothing to set. Just start notepad.exe.
    )

    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%~j" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%%~j" >NUL

    if errorlevel 1 (
        call :notstarted "%%~j"
    ) else call :started "%%~j"
)
exit /b


:notstarted
setlocal
echo started "%~1" at %time%

set "cli=start """

if defined startdir set "cli=%cli% /d "%startdir%""

if defined programpath (
    set "cli=%cli% "%programpath%\%~1""
) else set "cli=%cli% "%~1""

if defined args set "cli=%cli% %args%"

if defined changedir pushd "%changedir%"

echo %cli%
%cli%

if defined changedir popd
exit /b


:started
echo "%%~1" is already running......
exit /b
```

Your code has many unknowns so I have done an example which you
can adapt to your needs.

I chose some simple programs like notepad and wordpad to test with.

Variables for use are commented at the top of the script. These
variables are undefined at start of each loop so you do not need
to undefined them and just use the variables that you want to set
with each program.

The `errorlevel` of `tasklist` is checked and will call the name of
the label required. This allows the call to return back to the
position of the caller so the loop can continue.

The `:notstarted` label will bulid the command line (cli) with
each of the defined variables that are relevent to the cli. The
optional `pushd` and `popd` was added just for an unusual use.

Comment: Thanks a lot @micheal_heath your approach is much better if i need to open multiple programs with different `args`, i have learnt of a new way to use `call`,`pushd`and `popd`.However Could you please explain why you use `if "%%~j" == "wordpad.exe"` instead of  `if "%%j" == "wordpad.exe"` in your code?

Comment: `"%%~j"` ensures surrounding double quotes if any are stripped before adding double quotes. If any of your executables added to the list contain spaces and you would quote it i.e `"some file.exe"`, later use of `"%%j"` would become `""some file.exe""`. Using `"%~j"` can help to avoid the later issue of assuming whether surrounding double quotes exist or not.